# Send data to another app and get response from it

Tags: swift, macos, nsappleeventdescriptor

I'm trying to communicate apps with each other.

I'm handling Apple Events in my first application with

```
NSAppleEventManager.shared().setEventHandler(self, andSelector: #selector(handleGetURLEvent), forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass), andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL))

func handleGetURLEvent(_ event: NSAppleEventDescriptor, withReplyEvent replyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor)
```

In the second app I'm creating [NSAppleEventDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsappleeventdescriptor) object

```
let test = NSAppleEventDescriptor(string: "test")
let descriptor = NSAppleEventDescriptor(eventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass), eventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL), targetDescriptor: nil, returnID: AEReturnID(kAutoGenerateReturnID), transactionID: AETransactionID(kAnyTransactionID))
descriptor.setParam(test, forKeyword: keyDirectObject)
```

Now with `NSWorkspace` I'm launching my first app

```
NSWorkspace.shared().launchApplication(at: myAppUrl, options: .default, configuration: [NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationAppleEvent:descriptor])
```

Everything is ok, function `handleGetURLEvent` is called, but... `replyEvent.desciptorType` is `kAENullEvent` also I don't have clue how would I get `replyEvent` in my second app.

I suppose there is something wrong with this solution.

So my question is how can I simply send data to my other app and get some data back?

Comment: Perhaps if you try the exact same thing from the receiving app? I mean, the original app is already running, so perhaps `launchApplication(at:...` just passes the event to the already running app?

Comment: Seems like a good solution, but it won't work out in my case. I don't want the first application to know which application it would send response to.

Comment: Oh, you just need a generic “respond immediately to whoever woke me up”

Comment: Yes, you're right. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: What about this guy: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/distributednotificationcenter#main

Comment: Also, NSWorkspace has a `notificationCenter` property (of type vanilla NSNotificationCenter), but doesn’t look like it could work between apps...?